# Calculating a factorial with parallel sub-computations using pmap, pvalues and pcalls

Tags: clojure

In an attempt to learn more about Clojure's parallel computation functions, I devised the following task: calculate a factorial in parallel using `pmap`, `pcalls` and `pvalues`.

The idea is to split the factorial sequence into sub-computations, reducing the final output of each.

Here is the obvious non-parallel function:

```lisp
(defn factorial [n] (reduce * (range 1 (inc n))
```

pmap is fairly straight-forward:

```lisp
(defn pmap-factorial [n psz]
  (let [parts (partition-all psz (range 1 (inc n)))]
    (reduce * (pmap #(apply * %) parts))))
```

However, with pvalues I had to resort to macros that return a computation function.

```lisp
(defmacro pvalues-factorial [n psz]
  (let [exprs (for [p (partition-all psz (range 1 (inc n)))]
                 (cons '* p))]
    `(fn [] (reduce * (pvalues ~@exprs)))))
```

Similar approach with pcalls:

```lisp
(defmacro pcalls-factorial [n psz]
  (let [exprs (for [p (partition-all psz (range 1 (inc n)))]
                     `(fn [] (* ~@p)))]
    `(fn [] (reduce * (pcalls ~@exprs)))))
```

So, I had to use macros for `pcalls` and `pvalues`. Does not seem ideal, but it was the only way I could accomplish the above (and perhaps indicates that `pmaps` is the best practice for this use case).

**Questions:**

1) How could the code be made more correct / idiomatic?

2) Did I have to resort to macros for pvalues and pcalls, or have I overlooked another way of accomplishing my goal with these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) that is quite idomatic Clojure from what I have seen.

2) macros are "contagious" if the thing you are trying to call is a macro and you want to do anything requiring first-class-functions (map apply reduce etc...) then the thing doing the `apply`ing must it's self be a macro.

This is why the coding standards for clojure.contrib stable releases require that your library provide a non-macro way to access it's services in addition to the macro one. as your problem nicely demonstrates. 
**macros are incredibly useful, and they are not first class**